# Add filter in stored procedure but give error invalid

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

When I add filter in my stored procedure, it throws an error "invalid column name".

My query is:

```
select name, monthlysalary as ms 
from Patient 
where ms = 2000;
```

Comment: correct `select name, monthlysalary as ms from Patient where monthlysalary =2000;`

Comment: Procedural code (like stored procedures) is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag for the actual, concrete database **system** you're using - whether it be `mysql`, `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2` or something else entirely....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use aliases at where part

It should be like that.

```
select name, monthlysalary as ms from Patient where monthlysalary =2000;
```

Comment: Thanks Sir for help